# Sort Columns by assigned column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting, yfinance

I have a following code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import time


starttimer = time.time()

resp = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})

tickers = []

for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text
    tickers.append(ticker)

tickers = [s.replace('\n', '') for s in tickers]

start = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1)
data = yf.download("GOOGL", start=start, end=end)
print(data)

eodPrices   = pd.DataFrame(data=data);
percentageChange = round(eodPrices.pct_change()*100,2).shift(-1)
percentageChange.sort_values(by=['Close'],inplace=True)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(percentageChange,columns = ['Close'])
print(dataframe)
```

The code gets data for required ticker/s from yfinance module, then sort (Ascending) them. I receive following response:

[image]

I have several issues with this response:

I don't see a ticker in the response and when I try to download more tickers I receive following error:

**ValueError: The column label 'Close' is not unique.
For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.**

I don't know how to fix this.

My desired response should be as following:

[image]

Current date formatting:

[image]

I'd like to have just a date e.g. "2020-03-13". It seems to be hardcoded and I can't change it, is there a way how to do it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
tickers = ['AAPL', 'GOOGL']

start = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1)
data = yf.download(tickers, start=start, end=end)['Close']

dfs = []
for idx, ticker in enumerate(data.columns, 1):
    df = (data[ticker].pct_change().mul(100).round(2).shift(-1)
                      .sort_values(na_position='last').to_frame('Close')
                      .rename_axis('Date').reset_index())
    df.insert(1, 'Ticker', ticker)
    dfs.append(df.add_suffix(f' {idx}'))
out = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
        Date 1 Ticker 1  Close 1     Date 2 Ticker 2  Close 2
0   2020-03-13     AAPL   -12.86 2020-03-13    GOOGL   -11.63
1   2020-03-11     AAPL    -9.88 2020-03-11    GOOGL    -8.20
2   2020-09-02     AAPL    -8.01 2020-03-06    GOOGL    -6.17
3   2020-03-06     AAPL    -7.91 2020-10-27    GOOGL    -5.51
4   2020-09-04     AAPL    -6.73 2020-06-25    GOOGL    -5.45
..         ...      ...      ...        ...      ...      ...
501 2020-02-28     AAPL     9.31 2021-02-02    GOOGL     7.28
502 2020-03-23     AAPL    10.03 2020-04-03    GOOGL     8.28
503 2020-07-30     AAPL    10.47 2020-04-28    GOOGL     8.89
504 2020-03-12     AAPL    11.98 2020-03-12    GOOGL     9.24
505 2021-12-31     AAPL      NaN 2021-12-31    GOOGL      NaN

[506 rows x 6 columns]
```

**Update**

> I'd like to have just a date e.g. "2020-03-13". It seems to be hardcoded and I can't change it, is there a way how to do it?

The `out` dataframe is not really suitable for this task:

```
def extract_date(df, date):
    return df[df.iloc[:, 0] == date].reset_index(drop=True)  # date column
    
df1 = (out.groupby(out.columns.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False), axis=1, group_keys=False)
          .apply(extract_date, date='2020-03-13'))
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
      Date 1 Ticker 1  Close 1     Date 2 Ticker 2  Close 2
0 2020-03-13     AAPL   -12.86 2020-03-13    GOOGL   -11.63
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm.

2 questions though: 

1 - currently I have a formatting issue with date (please, check my initial question, I updated it

2 - is it possible to download entire table and then just select certain columns? In your case you download just columns we want.

Comment: Updated me question and comment. Thank you.

Comment: You want this date for all tickers from `out` dataframe?

Comment: Yes, all of them.

Comment: It's possible but I don't think your current dataframe (`out`) is not well designed to do this kind of operations.

Comment: @Thayskills. I updated my answer, can you check it please?

Comment: Tested and formatting remains unchanged.

Comment: What do you mean? `df1` is not the expected output?

Comment: My `out` output is not as yours. I want mine `out` output to be same as yours (date formatting wise). My current date formatting is as shown on picture, which  needs to be changed. My `df1` is same as my current `out` - in other words, no change.